# Excel - How to select / filter today's date from date range?

Tags: excel, date, filter

I have a project plan made in excel. It has items with their start date & end dates in 2 different columns. Say `item-A` starts on `20-Sep` & ends on `28-Sep`.

Every day I need to view items which need to be done today. So if today is `25-Sep`, I need to see/filter all items which fall in that date range (Eg item-A).

How do I filter that?

```
Item     Start Date     End Date
A        20-Sep         28-Sep
B        15-Sep         24-Sep
...
...
```

Comment: Do you accept a solution on Google Sheets?

Comment: Yes I accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say my testing data is like this.

```
        A       B       C       D
 1    Item    Start    End
 2      A    20-Sep  28-Sep
 3      B    15-Sep  24-Sep
 4      C    23-Sep  02-Oct
```

I came up with 2 methods. First is conditional formatting, the other is an autofilter.

## Conditional Formatting

Selecting A2, and formatting by formula:
`=AND(TODAY()>=$B2,TODAY()<=$C2)`
Then setting the format such as changing its interior color, and apply this to all your data range.

## Autofilter

We have to use an extra column for the condition to filter. Type `=AND(TODAY()>=$B2,TODAY()<=$C2)` into D2, and autofilter it with value `TRUE`.

## Autofilter-2

An autofilter can filter the date directly. You can set up the criteria of column B to before or equal to the date of today, and set up column C for after or equal to the date of today. However this has to be done by manual except using a macro, and I'm not using Eng. version excel so it's difficult for me to tell you which button step by step.